# Detect Mobile Browser Close Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-browser

Is there any way to detect mobile browser close event? I need to forcefully delete a cookie on browser close. I have already tried my luck with `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.unload` but they doesn't work for mobile browsers. Search on the web a lot but didn't get any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: set a cookie with a past expires time ?

Comment: Are you killing the browser tab ?

Comment: @Hacketo I need to do that after I get the close event.

Comment: This wouldn't work anyway. What if I just pulled the battery? Ask yourself this: If I don't want the data to be persistent, should I *really* be storing it in a cookie?

Comment: @RGraham Its kinda flag kind thing which I need across all the pages. I am not storing any data

Comment: What about a session cookie then? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202521/simulate-session-cookies-in-mobile-sessions) is worth a read

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal, why after the close event ? the browser will remove this cookie when the tab will be closed I guess.

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal you can use localstorage or sessionstorage in javascript to set and access data across webpages for a single session..

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry but it's just impossible with Javascript...
You can prevent the action of closing tab but not to do something when it will be close...

[How to Detect Browser Window /Tab Close Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227383/how-to-detect-browser-window-tab-close-event)

Answer (score 2):

Use $(window).blur(function() for mobile browsers.