# Sessions keep getting lost on mobile browsers

Tags: java, session, mobile, struts2, session-cookies

Currently, I am setting up user sessions on Java (with JSP on Struts 2 Framework) with the following code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
SessionBean sessionBean = new SessionBean();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(604800);
sessionBean.setUserBean(userBean);
session.setAttribute("sessionBean", sessionBean);
```

This session is terminated only when the user explicitly logs out with the following code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.removeAttribute("sessionBean");
```

While sessions automatically expire after 1 week (604800 seconds) of user inactivity.

The above works all fine and dandy on desktop browsers. However, on mobile browsers (observed on iPhone Safari and Android's default browser), the **session expires after the page is idle for 30 minutes or more**.

I just replicated the problem with the following steps:

- Opened the page on iPhone Safari, left the page idle and closed iPhone Safari (with it still running in the background).
- Reopened iPhone Safari 30 minutes later.
- The page refreshed and when it did so, my session was lost.

How do I preserve sessions on mobile such that the user stays logged in unless they explicitly logout (or their session expires within the standard 7 days of inactivity)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question, +1. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15391421/1654265